# Python regex spacing

Tags: python, regex, text

I have a sentence: "**this is not a good sentence**" and I am trying to insert an underscore (`_`) after the word not. The code I am using right now is

```
i = "this is not a good sentence"
i = re.sub(r'(not)', r'\1_', i)
```

this outputs: "**this is not_ a good sentence**"

I want it to output: "**this is not_a good sentence**"

How do I sub without the sentence shifting?I want "**not**" and "**a**" connected by the underscore but right now there is a space.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need RegEx at all, simply replace `not` with `not_`

```
i = "this is not a good sentence"
i = i.replace("not ", "not_")
```

Comment: `print('Let's talk about the connotation.'.replace('not ', 'not_'))`

Comment: @Matthias I know it will not work for this. But the point is, OP wants to use RegEx where it is absolutely not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. You just need to make the regex consume the whitespaces without including them in the capture group. This can be done by adding `\s*`:

```
In [8]: re.sub(r'\b(not)\s*\b', r'\1_', i)
Out[8]: 'this is not_a good sentence'
```

Note how I've used word boundaries (`\b`) to make sure `not` is never matched in the middle of a word.

Another way is to use [positive lookbehind](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
In [17]: re.sub(r'(?<=\bnot\b)\s*', r'_', i)
Out[17]: 'this is not_a good sentence'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* wanted to use regex:

```
i=re.sub(r'(not)\s?', r'\1_', i)
```

or specify the word boundary as well to ensure that it matches `not` and not `notion` or `knot`:

```
i=re.sub(r'(\bnot\b)\s?', r'\1_', i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = "this is not a good sentence"
i = re.sub(r'(not) +', r'\1_', i)
```

Just include the space in the find.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a space to the matching regular expression:

```
i = "this is not a good sentence"
i = re.sub(r'(not) ', r'\1_', i)
```